# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, html, css

Hi  I am creating a responsive navbar using flex box and bem methodology in angular 6,  I have added hamburger menu for mobile devices. but its not working here is what I have .

HTML:

```
<div class="Navbar">
    <div class="Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-brand">
       Website title
     </div>
     <div class="Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-toggle">
       <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
     </div>
   <nav class="Navbar__Items">
     <div class="Navbar__Link">
       Longer Link
     </div>
     <div class="Navbar__Link">
       Longer Link
     </div>
     <div class="Navbar__Link">
       Link
     </div>
   </nav>
   <nav class="Navbar__Items Navbar__Items--right">
     <div class="Navbar__Link">
       Link
     </div>
     <div class="Navbar__Link">
       Link
     </div>
   </nav>
 </div>
```

Here is my full CSS code

```
body { 
  margin: 0
}

.Navbar {
  background-color: #46ACC2;
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.Navbar__Link {
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.Navbar__Items {
  display: flex;
}

.Navbar__Items--right {
  margin-left:auto;
}

.Navbar__Link-toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .Navbar__Items,
  .Navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .Navbar__Items {
    display:none;
  }
  .Navbar__Items--right {
    margin-left:0;
  }
  .Navbar__ToggleShow {
    display: flex;
  }
  .Navbar__Link-toggle {
    align-self: flex-end;
    display: initial;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
   } 
}

Here is my js for toggle
function classToggle() {
  const navs = document.querySelectorAll('.Navbar__Items')

  navs.forEach(nav => nav.classList.toggle('Navbar__ToggleShow'));
}

document.querySelector('.Navbar__Link-toggle').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
```

and index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Majeni</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="./assets/js/toggle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> NOTE

I have created the same navbar in pure html and js everything works fine here is the fiddle to the working one : [Menu with Hamburger using BEM and flex Box](https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/9x1urqc5/5/)

But in my angular app When I run the app I get the following error in browser console,

> ﻿
>   toggle.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are you running that js snippet at in your code? Most likely what is happening is that your template has not been rendered yet when your code is running. That will cause your query selector to not find the DOM node in question and thus you will receive that null error you are getting.

Comment: i believe as i see , you are loading the script toggle.js from index.html, as the @DanielWStrimpel mentioned DOM is not rendered and the toggle.js script is running and it unable to find the element for click listener ,try adding             
 `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.querySelector('.Navbar__Link-toggle').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
  });`  in the toggle.js file so that after DOM is rendered , the add listener is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular application don't use JQuery or JS native api Angular has a way to handle dom manipulation

Use Directive for Add and remove Class

```
import { Directive,HostListener,HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSidebar]',
  exportAs:'appSidebar'
})
export class SidebatDirective {
@HostBinding('class.is-open') click=false;
  constructor() { }        
@HostListener('click') onClic(){
this.click=!this.click;
}
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-nabar

Comment: Thanks , @chellappan so is it posible to use bootstrap toggle in my code with BEM methodology? assume I dont want to use js or directive,  if yes Can you please provide an example?

Comment: BEM is css naming convention it has nothing to do with angular you can use with angular no issue

Comment: I have tried to add hamburger menu using bootstrap toggle but its hidden not showing on desktop version  here is link : https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/rjysf257/1/  can you please help?   what is wrong with my code?

Comment: use css preprocessor to convert scss to normal css change css into scss in your fiddle it will work

Comment: I tried everything my problem is the hamburger button is showing up on desktop device, that is wrong I just want to  shown only on mobile device as in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/starter-template/   , did you check it ? https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/rjysf257/7/

Comment: No I think it doesnt work with bem , your method is best just adding custom directive